# Почему не выводится ошибка при завершения bash-скрипта?

Tags: bash, консоль, shell

Когда в bash скрипте я обращаюсь к не существующему файлу, скрипт выдает ошибку и завершает работу из-за этой ошибке.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# чтобы скрипт автоматически завершался при ошибке
set -e

# читаем из файла
read < file

# не выполняется, так как была ошибка при чтение
echo no-continue
```

В терминал выводится:

```
./test: line 5: file: No such file or directory
```

Но когда я обращаюсь к пустому файлу, скрипт тоже завершается из-за ошибки, но не выводит никакую ошибку. почему?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# чтобы скрипт автоматически завершался при ошибке
set -e

# создаем файл
touch file
# читаем из файла
read < file

# не выполняется, так как была ошибка при чтение
echo no-continue
```

В терминал ни чего не выводится. Почему не выводит ошибку в терминал?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае ошибка относится не к `read`, а к самому интерпретатору: он не может создать перенаправление `< file`, о чём и сообщает.

Во втором случае `read` возвращается с ненулевым кодом, прочитав файл `file` [до конца](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read):

> The exit status is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered

Для `read` этот ненулевой код не является ошибкой. Так как в большинстве случаев `read` используется внутри циклов `while read ... ; do ... ; done`, конец файл должен приводить к выходу из цикла. Ненулевой статус `read` как раз обеспечивает выход из цикла. Если бы `read` каждый раз печатал сообщение о `EOF`, это было бы очень неудобно.

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили. 
Однако почему после того как я добавили set -e в свой скрипт, и read возвращает не нулевое значение мой скрипт неожиданно завершается, как буто произошла ошибка.

Comment: @7vasko `set -e` завершает скрипт в случае ненулевого кода завершения конвейера команд. В первом случае ненулевой код выставляет сам шелл из-за ошибки в перенаправлении. Во втором случае код выставляет команда `read`.